# RelationShip Between DeliveryName Field In SalesTable in Dynamics AX

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012

**I Need to retrive the DeliveryName Field From SalesTable..What is the relationShip Between them ??How Can i retrive the DeliveryName From SalesTable **

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional information that you gave in your comments. Your question in its current state is very unclear for new readers.

Answer (score 2):

for the comments you want get `DeliveryName` from `SalesTable` but you need the relation between `CustInvoiceJour` and `SalesTable`.

The relation is `CustInvoiceJour.SalesId == SalesTable.SalesId`

**Code:**

```
Select DeliveryName from SalesTable where SalesTable.SalesId == CustInvoiceJour.SalesId;
```

Comment: hey thank u.. that same way how can i take the WorkerSalesTaker, WorkerSalesResponsible  ,field in sales table...Help me??

Comment: Change this **Select DeliveryName from SalesTable where SalesTable.SalesId == CustInvoiceJour.SalesId;** and put this **Select * from SalesTable where SalesTable.SalesId == CustInvoiceJour.SalesId;** Now with the ***** you can take any field.

Comment: @VinothYesuraj: Please create new questions for follow up questions. Try to avoid asking them in comments, as this makes it harder for other people to find these questions and their answer.

Answer (score 0):

[`DeliveryName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/salestable.aspx#DeliveryName) is field on `SalesTable` - there is no special relation as this is plain text field.

Comment: then how can i retrive that field using any condition

Comment: give us example what do you want to do

Comment: **select DeliveryNamefrom salesTable where salesTable.CustInvoiceId==custInvoiceJour.InvoiceId;**

Comment: The above querry which i need to retrive the DeliveryName Using any relationship

Comment: Can your question be rephrased as: how to find the sales order of an invoice? Once you have the sales order the field is there. But again, why not use `CustInvoiceJour.DeliveryName`?

Comment: hey by using above querry only i could not get what i want....so can u suggest me any querry to get the Delivery Name of sales Table...